# Are there more truth-values for many valued logics than 1, 0, b, and n?

Tags: logic

I have to create a many valued logic and am having trouble coming up with my set V. Can I include truth-values which retain a notion of probability, for example mt (mostly true) or mf (mostly false)?

Comment: There is [continuous logic](https://www.google.com/search?q="continuous+logic") and [fuzzy logic](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fuzzy+logic%22) (truth values range over the closed interval $[0,1]),$ [complex truth values](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22complex+truth+value%22) (truth values can be negative real numbers, and even non-real complex numbers), and [Boolean valued models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean-valued_model) (truth values range of some specified complete Boolean algebra). And there are probably more exotic things, as I'm hardly an expert on this stuff.

Comment: Thank you. I think fuzzy logic sounds interesting.